# plot mirror image of data using gnuplot

Tags: shell, plot, gnuplot

I have a datafile

```
1 0.124
2 0.3
3 0.8
4 1.2
5 -
6 -
7 -
8 -
```

Where values of 5,6,7,8 are mirror image of the previous half data. i.e. f(5) = f(4) f(6) = f(3) etc.. I have a large file like this and want to plot the data with gnuplot. how can I do this in gnuplot?

I tried,

```
p 'data.dat' u 1:($1>4 ? :$2)
```

where I want to mention use column 2 of (8-$1).

Comment: In general you cannot access other rows than the current one. Unless you have some relation between the x-values of the first part and those of the second part, you should preprocess the data file with an external tool.

Answer (score 0):

```
p 'data.dat' u 1:($1>4 ? 1/0 :$2) w l, 'data.dat' u (8-$1):($1<4 ? 1/0 :$2) w l
```

As Christoph said only one row can be read at one time, I call the same file twice first using natural arguments and second time with mirrored arguments.

Comment: Since you mentioned that you have a large file I thought you would need more processing

Comment: @Christoph, I have indeed a large file, but this answer is in accordance with the question.

Answer (score 0):

According to your specification in your question, your second command should be `... u (9-$1):...`

Furthermore, if you have a large file you don't need to plot >1000 times `1/0` or `NaN` and you don't need the ternary operator.
You have the option `every` where you can only plot a part of the file, check `help every`. And you can automatically determine the number of datapoints with `stats`, check `help stats`.

**Data:**

```
1 0.124
2 0.3
3 0.8
4 1.2
5 -
6 -
7 -
8 -
```

**Script:**

```
### plot mirrored data
reset session

FILE = "SO29543315.dat"

stats FILE u 0 nooutput   # get the number of datapoints
N = STATS_records

plot FILE u 1:2        every ::::N/2-1 w lp pt 7, \
       '' u (N-$1+1):2 every ::::N/2-1 w lp pt 7
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]